Is this identity between the Fourier and Laplace transforms true?
I have been given this definition of the Laplace transform:
$``$Let $ \mathbb{R}_0^+ = [0, \infty) $. The Laplace transform of a function $ f : \mathbb{R}_0^+ \to \mathbb{C} $, for $ p = \sigma + i\tau $ with real $ \sigma $ and $ \tau $, is defined as:
$$
F(p) = (\mathcal{L}f)(p) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt} \, dt, \tag{1}
$$
assuming the integral exists.
For $ a \in \mathbb{R} $, it is said that $ f \in E_a $ if
$$
\int_0^\infty |f(t)|e^{-at} \, dt < +\infty."
$$
I was investigating whether there were any relationships with the Fourier transforms I studied. And I have been told that this is true, but I don't know:
$``$If $ f \in E_a $, then
$$
(\mathcal{L}f)(p) = \mathcal{F}(e_\sigma f)(\tau),
$$
where $ e_\sigma(t) = e^{-\sigma t} $ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.$"$
Any idea?

Let $f \in E_a$. The relationship between Fourier Transform $\mathcal{F}$ and Laplace Transform $\mathcal{L}$ is: $\forall \sigma \in [a,\infty) , \tau \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\mathcal{L}(f) (\sigma + i \tau ) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-(\sigma + i \tau ) t } \, dt = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-\sigma t} e^{- i \tau t} dt =\mathcal{F}(\hat f \cdot e^{-\sigma \bullet})(\tau),
$$
where $\hat f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}, \ \hat f (t):= f(t), $ if $t\geq 0$ and $0$ else.
An interesting application of this is the following assuming $f \in L^2([0, \infty))$: For all $\sigma \in [0, \infty)$:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\mathcal{L}(f) (\sigma + i \tau)|^2 d\tau 
&= \|\mathcal{F}(\hat f \cdot e^{-\sigma \bullet})\|_2^2 \\
&= C \| \hat f \cdot e^{-\sigma \bullet}\|_2^2 \\
&= C \int_{0}^\infty |f (t) e^{-\sigma t}|^2 dt \leq C \|f\|_2^2< \infty.
\end{align}$$
Here $C>0$ is some constant from using Plancherels Theorem for the Fourier Transform for the second equality.
This shows (assuming that we know that $\mathcal{L}(f)$ is holomorphic) that the Laplace transform maps $L^2([0, \infty))$ into $H^2$ (the second Hardy space on the right half plane) and that $ \sqrt{C} \|f\|_{L^2} =  \| \mathcal{L}(f)\|_{H_2}$. The converse that every $H^2$ function is the Laplace transform of some $L^2$ function is the so called Payley Wiener Theorem.

But in particular, you should prove that if $f \in E_a$ and $g \in E_a$ and $c=max{a,b}$ and $F(p)=G(p)$ in $H_c$, then, $f=g$ almost for all

@Emma why should i prove that? Neither the question nor my answer is about injectivity of the Laplace transform.

@Emma Also what are $b$ and $H_c$ in your comment?!

$\bar{H_a}={p\in \mathbb{C}: \mathfrak{R}p \geq a}$

I forgot to write it, sorry!!
